# netlogo comparing turtle variables

Tags: compare, netlogo

I'm writing a program which groups turtles into different groups. 
I am trying to write a command where if there is a turtle in a different group within a 1 until radius of the turtle the command runs.

This is what I have

```
to confront
  ask turtles
   [if [ group ] of turtles in-cone 1 180 != group  
    [set color brown]]
end
```

However the command is coming out true even when there is not a turtle in a different group nearby.

Answer (score 0):

may be something like :

```
to confront
  ask turtles
   if any? turtles in radius 2 [
     if any? turtles in radius 2 with [group != [group] of myself][
      set color brown
     ]
   ]
end
```

I don't know if it can work directly (I haven't test this code) but I think it's a way

Comment: looks right to me (also not tested) but I don't think you need the first `if any?` - if there aren't any turtles in radius, there certainly aren't any that belong to some other group